# Easiest way to safely get the equivalent of SUID on a shell script

Tags: shell-script, sudo, suid

I have a script in which I need to mount an overlay to give an OCI container access to a mounted read-only directory `/nix/store` as if it was writable.

I would like to have this script be runnable by non-root/non-wheel users, what would be the easiest way? Initially, I naively tried using `SUID` before I realized that those didn't work, which lead me to a bunch of answers and articles on the dangers of `SUID` for shell scripts, including one that explained why merely wrapping it around some C program would not fix the security issues regarding non-clean environment.

Is there an easy wrapper/utility I can wrap the script in that takes care of such vulnerabilities?

From the user environment, I only need one ENV which is just passed to the docker container, however, the root user would have the same ENV variable in their bash session, therefore if a suggestion works by disregarding all the user environment and instead uses the root one, that would be fine for my use case.

```
local temp_dir=$(mktemp -d)

mkdir -p {$temp_dir/store,$temp_dir/upper-store,$temp_dir/work-store}

# Create Overlay
sudo mount -t overlay overlay \
  -o lowerdir=/nix/store,upperdir=$temp_dir/upper-store,workdir=$temp_dir/work-store $temp_dir/store

# Do some sutff with the mounted overlay

sudo umount $temp_dir/store
rm -rf $temp_dir
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for sudo, as you already tagged

Comment: @MarcusMüller But I would like this to be runnable by non-wheel users, like an `SUID` binary

Comment: Yes, sudo can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few variables here, it will depend on which distro you are using and whether or not it adds all users to **a** group. I'm running ubuntu atm, and all my local users are part of `plugdev`.

So if I wanted to allow all of them to run your script I'd add this line to `/etc/sudoers.d/script`:

```
%plugdev  ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

You should then also be able to  eliminate the use of `sudo` from within the script (the *mounting* & *unmounting*).
You obviously need to have that script in a PATH they all can see, but preferably so they can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to offer mount / umount access
to your users is via `sudo`, as already implemented
in the script.
Or perhaps wrap the script and use `sudo wrapper.sh`
if you prefer to log fewer syslog records.

> I would like this to be runnable by non-wheel users

`$ man 5 sudoers` offers extensive advice on how to
correctly configure the utility to satisfy your use case.
Stack Overflow also has a couple three answers on this topic.